# Nutch 2.3 - javax.net.ssl.SSLException

Tags: apache, web-crawler, nutch

I am using Apache Nutch 2.3 but I cannot crawl SSL domains. I'm getting the following error:

> fetch of https://example.com/ failed with: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error

I'm getting the same error with

Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (1.8.0_66 25.66-b17)

and

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.8) (7u121-2.6.8-1ubuntu0.14.04.1)